# Heisenbug with own headless browser

Tags: javascript, c++, webkit, qt4, headless-browser

I'm working on a headless browser based on WebKit (using C++/Qt4) with JavaScript support. The main purpose for this is being able to generate a HTML spanshot of websites heavily based on JavaScript (see Backbone.js or any other JavaScript MVC).

I'm aware that there isn't any way for knowing *when* the page is completely loaded (please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604365/checking-for-pending-calls)) and because of that, after I get the `loadFinished` signal (docs [here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qwebview.html#loadFinished)) I create a timer and start polling the DOM content (as in checking every X ms the content of the DOM) to see if there were any changes. If there werent I assume that the page was loaded and print the result. Please keep in mind that I already know this is not-near-to-perfect solution, but it's the only one I could think of. If you have any better idea please answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604365/checking-for-pending-calls)

*NOTE: The timer is non-blocking, meaning that everything running inside WebKit shouldn't be affected/blocked/paused in any way.*

After testing the headless browser with some pages, everything seems to work fine (or at least as expected). But here is where the heisenbug appears. The headless browser should be called from a PHP script, which should wait (blocking call) for some output and then print it.

On my test machine (Apache 2.3.14, PHP 5.4.6) running the PHP script outputs the desired result, aka, the headless browser fetches the website, runs the JavaScript and prints what a user would see; but running the same script in the production server will fetch the website, run *some* of the JavaScript code and print the result.

The source code of the headless browser and the PHP script I'm using can be found [here](https://github.com/alexandernst/headless_browser).

*NOTE: The timer (as you can see in the source code of the headless browser) is set to 1s, but setting a bigger amount of time doesn't fix the problem*

*NOTE 2: Catching all JavaScript errors doesn't show anything, so it's not because of a missing function, wrong args, or any other type of incorrect code.*

I'm testing the headless browser with 2 websites.
[This one](http://coenraets.org/directory/#employees/11) is working on both my test machine and in production server, while [this one](http://www.agcinmo.com/#!listado/venta/chalets/) works only in my test machine.

I'm more propone to think that this is some weird bug in the JavaScript code in the second website rather than in the code of the headless browser, as it generates a perfect HTML snapshot of the first website, but then again, this is a heisenbug so I'm not really sure what is causing all this.

Any ideas/comments will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I don't understand the close votes. Please tell me what's wrong with this question.

Comment: Would be interesting to know 1. at what point the JS code on prod server is executed and 2. what the differences between dev and prod server are.

Comment: @hongaar The code is executed after the page is completely loaded (```$(document).ready(f...)```). There's a small "loading" widget that is generated with JS (which I do see after running the PHP on the prod machine), and meanwhile an AJAX request is made. The AJAX callback is processed by Backbone, the "loading" widget is removed and the real data is placed on the DOM. (this part isn't done on the prod machine but only in my test machine).

Comment: @hongaar The differences between the prod and the test machines are mainly the speed (the prod is kind of slower). Also, the test machine is x86 while the prod is x64, but that shouldn't matter, should it? I can post exact specs if you want me to.

Comment: Does it stop loading at "deploy/libs.js"?

Comment: @hongaar no, it doesn't. It loads all required JS's, then creates the header, the footer and makes a AJAX request for the data needed for the body content. But what happens next is a mistery. I'm not sure if the request doesn't finish/gets received or there's an error after the request has finished.

Comment: Have you tried putting a proxy like Fiddler or Wireshark between your application and the network to inspect what requests are made and what responses received, comparing the dev and prod machine?

Comment: @hongaar Yes, everything is received ok (on both test and prod machines). Things get even weirder. Running the headless browser (in the prod machine) from the command line (passing as first arg the "non-working" website) prints everything as expected (as in all the JS code was executed). But making the PHP script run the exactly same command makes the headless browser run only some of the JS.  (On my test machine both ways work fine)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20342/discussion-between-hongaar-and-alexandernst)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than polling for DOM changes, why not watch network requests? This seems like a safer heuristic to use. If there has been no network activity for X ms (and there are no pending requests), then assume page is fully "loaded".

Comment: I thought about that too. But what if page was made with Backbone.JS (Angular, Batman, whatever...) and is doing some heavy DOM changes without making any requests?